# net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JWT token is invalid

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am not able to connect with the snowflake using the pyspark in databricks.

```
def readFromSnowflake():
      private_key = ""
      sfOptions = {
            "sfURL": "swiggy.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
            "sfUser": "<user>",
            "sfDatabase": "<database>",
            "sfSchema": "<schema>",
            "sfWarehouse": "<warehouse>",
            "sfRole": "<role>",
            "pem_private_key": private_key
        }
      query = "<query>"
      SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
      df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query", query).load()
      df.show(10)
    
      
      
    readFromSnowflake()
```

when I run the above code in databricks notebook, I am getting below error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o318.load.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JWT token is invalid.
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:585)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:272)
    at net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:543)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initialize(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:167)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:119)
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:169)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:214)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(SnowflakeRelation.scala:61)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(SnowflakeRelation.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema$lzycompute(SnowflakeRelation.scala:58)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.schema(SnowflakeRelation.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone help me what might be causing the issue? But I am sure that rest of the options that I am passing in `sf_option` are correct.

Comment: Is the key pair authentication setup properly? Have you tried using just user/pass to see if you can connect?

Comment: Yes. Im able to run queries in snowflake dashboard

Comment: How have you tested key pair authentication ? Do you have a sample script?

Comment: key pair is working fine. query being executed into snowflake and somehow it is internally getting modified.

Comment: Can you get the [**JDBC log**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) generated as it should provide more information on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out after a week of trial and errors.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import re

spark = SparkSession.builder \
              .config("spark.jars", "path/to/snowflake-spark-connector.jar,path/to/snowflake-jdbc-library.jar,path/to/snowflake-jdbc-fips-library.jar") \
              .config("path/to/snowflake-spark-connector.jar,path/to/snowflake-jdbc-library.jar,path/to/snowflake-jdbc-fips-library.jar") \
              .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
              .getOrCreate()

spark._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeConnectorUtils.disablePushdownSession(
    spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate())

with open(path/to/your/rsa_key.p8, "rb") as key_file:
    p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    key_file.read(),
    password="<your private key password>".encode(),
    backend=default_backend()
    )

pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)
 
pkb = pkb.decode("UTF-8")

pkb = re.sub("-*(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-*\n","",pkb).replace("\n","")
 
sfOptions = {
    "sfURL" : "<ACCOUNT>.<REGION>.<CLOUDPROVIDER>.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfAccount" : "<ACCOUNT>",
    "sfUser" : "<USER>",
    "pem_private_key": pkb,
    "sfDatabase" : "<DATABASE>",
    "sfSchema" : "<SCHEMA>",
    "sfWarehouse" : "<WAREHOUSE>",
    "sfRole": "<ROLE>",
    "tracing": "ALL",
}
 
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions).option("query",  "<TABLE>").load()
df.show()
```

Also here are the URLs for the downloading the necessary jars.

https://search.maven.org/search?q=snowflake-jdbc

https://search.maven.org/search?q=spark-snowflake

There is a way to do it where you have the jars automatically downloaded but I figured I show the manual way here so there's no hand waving.

I think this is a non-issue for folks who are using snowflake and have the a URL that require them to identify the region. Think this setup is needed for Snowflake environments that require the region which is now considered the legacy setup.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html

So in your specific use case I would update your sfOptions to the following

```
sfOptions = {
            "sfURL": "swiggy.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
            "sfAccount" : "swiggy",
            "sfUser": "<user>",
            "sfDatabase": "<database>",
            "sfSchema": "<schema>",
            "sfWarehouse": "<warehouse>",
            "sfRole": "<role>",
            "pem_private_key": pkb
        }
```